# How does open inventor / coin3d enable two-sided rendering like OpenGL？

Tags: openinventor, coin3d

Coin3D uses single-sided rendering by default like the image below：

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [gitee.com](https://gitee.com/fenghezhi/Pictures/raw/master/img/Snipaste_2020-12-17_11-37-10.png))</sub>

How does open inventor / coin3d enable two-sided rendering like OpenGL？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoShapeHints is the answer, but this summary may be clearer:

- Two-sided lighting and backface culling are disabled by default.
- Two-sided lighting: enabled if *not solid* and *ordered vertices*.
  Set vertexOrdering to COUNTERCLOCKWISE (usually) or CLOCKWISE.
- Backface culling: enabled if *solid* and *ordered vertices*.
  Set shapeType to SOLID.

Comment: I got it, just need to set the  vertexOrdering.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [SoShapeHints](https://coin3d.github.io/Coin/html/classSoShapeHints.html#details) node before the geometry in the scenegraph either with `shapeType` set to `UNKNOWN_SHAPE_TYPE` if you already set the `vertexOrdering` to `CLOCKWISE` or `COUNTERCLOCKWISE`, or with the `vertexOrdering` set to `UNKNOWN_ORDERING` for any shape type, e.g.

```
ShapeHints {
    vertexOrdering UNKNOWN_ORDERING
    shapeType UNKNOWN_SHAPE_TYPE
}
```

For further explanation see the [SoShapeHints](https://coin3d.github.io/Coin/html/classSoShapeHints.html#details) documentation of Coin3D